# Substraction from two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

Since my problem is somewhat particular, I haven't yet found and answer, after very long searches, so here it goes: I have two tables: In_Stock and Out_Stock. I use the following selects:

**IN_Stock:**

```
select 
INs.CatID as CategoryID, 
INs.SubCatID as SubcategoryID, Sum(INs.Quantity) as QuantityIN
from IN_Stock INs
group by INs.CatID, INs.SubCatID
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ CategoryID ║ SubcategoryID ║ QuantityIN ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║          2 ║             9 ║ 0          ║
║          1 ║            16 ║ 8          ║
║          1 ║            27 ║ 5          ║
║          1 ║            30 ║ 160        ║
║          1 ║            31 ║ 6          ║
║          1 ║            39 ║ 35         ║
║          1 ║            40 ║ 7          ║
║          2 ║            44 ║ 13         ║
║          2 ║            54 ║ 6          ║
║          2 ║            70 ║ 5          ║
║          3 ║            87 ║ 3,5        ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

**OUT_Stock:**

```
select 
OUTs.CatID as CategoryID, 
OUTs.SubCatID as SubcategoryID, 
Sum(OUTs.Quantity) as QuantityOUT
from OUT_Stock OUTs
group by OUTs.CatID, OUTs.SubCatID
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ CategoryID ║ SubcategoryID ║ QuantityOUT ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║          1 ║            30 ║          30 ║
║          1 ║            39 ║          15 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**What I get is this table bellow (and it's obviously not right).**

```
select
INs.CatID as CategoryID, 
INs.SubCatID as SubcategoryID, 
Sum(INs.Quantity) as QuantityIN,
SUM(OUTs.Quantity) as QuantityOUT,
SUM(INs.Quantity)- SUM(OUTs.Quantity) as RemainingQuantity
from IN_Stock INs
left join OUT_Stock OUTs on INs.CatID=OUTs.CatID and INs.SubCatid=OUTs.SubCatid
group by INs.catid, INs.subcatid

╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CategoryID ║ SubcategoryID ║ QuantityIN  ║ QuantityOUT║ RemainingQuantity ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║          2 ║             9 ║ 0           ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            16 ║ 8           ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            27 ║ 5           ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            30 ║ 320         ║        150 ║               170 ║
║          1 ║            31 ║ 6           ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            39 ║ 35          ║         30 ║                 5 ║
║          1 ║            40 ║ 7           ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            44 ║ 13          ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            54 ║ 6           ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            70 ║ 5           ║            ║                   ║
║          3 ║            87 ║ 3,5         ║            ║                   ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

**What i want is to make a select in SQL that returns something like the table bellow**... and I would like to know if and how can I see in RemaningStock collumn: **130** where SubcategoryID=30 and **20** where SubCategoryID=39.

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ CategoryID ║ SubcategoryID ║ QuantityIN ║ QuantityIN ║ RemainingQuantity ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║          2 ║             9 ║ 0          ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            16 ║ 8          ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            27 ║ 5          ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            30 ║ 160        ║         30 ║               130 ║
║          1 ║            31 ║ 6          ║            ║                   ║
║          1 ║            39 ║ 35         ║         15 ║                20 ║
║          1 ║            40 ║ 7          ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            44 ║ 13         ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            54 ║ 6          ║            ║                   ║
║          2 ║            70 ║ 5          ║            ║                   ║
║          3 ║            87 ║ 3,5        ║            ║                   ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Both tables have one or multiple records for a certain category or subcategory
Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks!
Either SQL or Access VBA code is good for me.
**PS:** As this is my first post please be "gentle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your final query makes the joins on individual rows in the initial dataset and only then performs the aggregation, whereas you would want to perform the joins on the intermediate sums.

Assuming this test data, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_in (
  id INTEGER,
  value INTEGER
  );

CREATE TABLE table_out (
  id INTEGER,
  value INTEGER
  );

INSERT INTO table_in(id, value) VALUES
  (1, 120),
  (1, 10);

INSERT INTO table_out(id, value) VALUES
  (1, 30);
```

The way you're writing the `LEFT JOIN` in your last query:

```
SELECT t1.value AS val1, t2.value AS val2
    FROM table_in t1 LEFT JOIN table_out t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

would produce these rows, before aggregation:

```
ID     VAL1        VAL2
1      120         30
1      10          30
```

Here, the sum would then give this:

```
ID      SUM(VAL1)    SUM(VAL2)
1       130          60
```

This will happen any time there's more than one row for the conditions used for the join.

You need to perform the join *after* the aggregate operations, since you want to compare the sum of all inputs, to the sum of all outputs.

This can be done using subselect statements, or [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

For example:

```
WITH sum_in AS (
  SELECT id, SUM(value) AS all_in
     FROM table_in
  GROUP BY id
), sum_out AS (
  SELECT id, SUM(value) AS all_out
     FROM table_out
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT t1.id, all_in, all_out, all_in - all_out
    FROM sum_in t1 LEFT JOIN sum_out t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: `WITH SUM_IN AS (
  SELECT INs.Catid, INs.Subcatid, SUM(INs.Quantity) AS all_in
     FROM IN_Stock INs
  GROUP BY INs.catid, INs.subcatid
), SUM_OUT AS (
  SELECT OUTs.Catid, OUTs.Subcatid, SUM(OUTs.Quantity) AS all_out
     FROM OUT_Stock OUTs
  GROUP BY OUTs.catid, OUTs.subcatid
)
SELECT T1.CatID as CategoryID, T1.SubCatID as SubcategoryID, ALL_IN as QuantityIN, ALL_OUT as QuantityOUT, ALL_IN - ALL_OUT as RemainingQuantity
    FROM SUM_IN T1 LEFT JOIN SUM_OUT T2 ON T1.CatID=T2.CatID and T1.SubCatID=T2.SubCatID` Works like a charm with some minor adjustment... THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries to get what you want, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT INs.catid         AS CategoryID,
           INs.subcatid      AS SubcategoryID,
           SUM(INs.quantity) AS QuantityIN
    FROM   in_stock INs
    GROUP  BY INs.catid,
              INs.subcatid) AS a
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT OUTs.catid         AS CategoryID,
                     OUTs.subcatid      AS SubcategoryID,
                     SUM(OUTs.quantity) AS QuantityOUT
              FROM   out_stock OUTs
              GROUP  BY OUTs.catid,
                        OUTs.subcatid) AS b
          ON ( a.subcategoryid = b.subcategoryid )
             AND ( a.categoryid = b.categoryid );
```

From this, it is very easy indeed to edit and modify the query using the Query Design Window in MS Access

```
SELECT a.categoryid,
   a.subcategoryid,
   a.quantityin,
   b.quantityout,
   [quantityin] - [quantityout] AS RemainingQuantity
FROM   (SELECT INs.catid         AS CategoryID,
           INs.subcatid      AS SubcategoryID,
           SUM(INs.quantity) AS QuantityIN
    FROM   in_stock INs
    GROUP  BY INs.catid,
              INs.subcatid) AS a
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT OUTs.catid         AS CategoryID,
                     OUTs.subcatid      AS SubcategoryID,
                     SUM(OUTs.quantity) AS QuantityOUT
              FROM   out_stock OUTs
              GROUP  BY OUTs.catid,
                        OUTs.subcatid) AS b
          ON ( a.subcategoryid = b.subcategoryid )
             AND ( a.categoryid = b.categoryid );
```

Comment: WOW that was quick ...  It's **good so far**, but actualy what i'm interested in is the RemaningQuantity collumn.

Comment: The remaining quantity can easily be added using the query design window, in fact, you now have a lit of control over filters and fields with the design window and the above sql.