# How can I write this cell-referenced Excel formula in VBA to use in MS Access: (b2-a1)

Tags: vba

This is a very simple calculation to do in Excel but I am stumped on how to do this within Access using 2 fields in a table in different records. One application I have needs to find the difference between an operation STOPTime and the next STARTTime. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am new to VBA.

Comment: This is in Access? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Based on your comments below it looks like you are trying to compare two separate records. We need some more data to help you out because "B2 - A1" in Access verbiage is a little more complicated

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use two separate records. How can I help you help me? Here are several start times: 8:15, 8:26, 8:42, 9:01, 9:30. endtimes: 8:21, 8:32, 8:58, 9:19, 9:43.
First difference is null, then 0:05, 0:10, 0:03, 0:11.
I was thinking that the procedure could call (stoptime) and next(startime) for a loop. Any way to number the records or build arrays with different beginning values? Sorry if I'm duplicating my comments. I'm not used to forums.

Comment: What else is in your table. I guess what I'm expecting is something that looks like one of [these](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14938153/substraction-from-two-different-tables-in-sql) tables. All the associated data is important. i.e. need to know why choose one start time over another.

Comment: An example is a welding operation. The table identifies the weld number, date, start time and end time. Based on start and stop times, I need to find 1) the time the welder is welding (stop time-start time) and 2) time that the welder is not welding, i.e. time between welds (next start time - last end time). 
Weld Start  Stop      CalcDuration     CalcIdle
1    7:15    7:22          0:07           -----
2    8:11    8:24          0:13           0:49
3    8:28    8:50          0:22           0:04
4    8:58    9:12          0:14           0:08
5    10:06   10:24         0:18           0:54

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub samPle()
Dim startTime As Date
Dim endTime As Date

startTime = Time
'''Your Code


endTime = Time

Debug.Print DateDiff("n", startTime, endTime) ' difference in minutes

End Sub
```

Comment: Field1 StartTime1 8:04 StartTime2 8:10
Field2 EndTime1 8:05   StopTime2  8:11
Need EndTime1 - StartTime2 = :05

Comment: Field1 StartTime1 8:04 StartTime2 8:10
Field2 EndTime1 8:05   StopTime2  8:11
Need EndTime1 - StartTime2 = :05

Comment: msgbox DateDiff("s", startTime, endTime) ' for  difference in seconds

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach the problem depending in your data, which makes posting data for questions about SQL very important. For example:

Table:

```
ID  EventTime           EventType
1   17/02/2013 08:52:00 start
2   17/02/2013 09:52:00 stop
3   17/02/2013 11:52:00 start
4   17/02/2013 15:52:00 stop
```

SQL:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.eventtime                    AS Start,
       a.eventtype,
       (SELECT TOP 1 eventtime
        FROM   times b
        WHERE  eventtype = "stop"
               AND eventtime > a.eventtime
        ORDER  BY eventtime,
                  id)                 AS Stop,
       Datediff("n", [start], [stop]) AS RunTime
FROM   times AS a
WHERE  (( ( a.eventtype ) = "start" ))
ORDER  BY a.eventtime;
```

Result:

```
ID  Start               EventType   Stop                RunTime
1   17/02/2013 08:52:00 start       17/02/2013 09:52:00     60
3   17/02/2013 11:52:00 start       17/02/2013 15:52:00     240
```

Re comment

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.eventtime                         AS Start, 
       a.eventtype, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 eventtime 
        FROM   times b 
        WHERE  eventtype = "stop" 
               AND eventtime > a.eventtime 
        ORDER  BY eventtime, 
                  id)                      AS Stop, 
       Datediff("n", [start], [stop])      AS RunTime, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 eventtime 
        FROM   times b 
        WHERE  eventtype = "start" 
               AND eventtime > a.eventtime 
        ORDER  BY eventtime, 
                  id)                      AS NextStart, 
       Datediff("n", [start], [nextstart]) AS StartDiff, 
       Datediff("n", [stop], [nextstart])  AS DownTime 
FROM   times AS a 
WHERE  (( ( a.eventtype ) = "start" )) 
ORDER  BY a.eventtime;
```

Comment: Thank you. I also need time inbetween start times or in the above case, 120 minutes.

Comment: Using the idea in the first statement, you can add other differences. It is best to post sample data when you have a specific requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by in VBA? You can save the query as a query and use it with a recordset or with a form and similarly you can copy the sql as a string to a variable and use that or copy the sql as a string to the recordsource of a form. To save the sql as a query, simply paste it into sql view of the query design window and save or run the query, having made suitable changes for your system.

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications. We currently do not use any programming languages. I am trying to learn how to do procedures that are not pre-programmed by MicroSoft.